# Power BI DAX - find values at max and min date in matrix

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, measure

My Power BI data model:

[image]

I have a matrix visual where I want to find value at min date and at max date:

[image]

Also I need a date filter. For example, if a user selects 03-04.01.2020 dates in filter, the measure should be recalculated and display this result:

[image]